# Failed to init PPM/PPM reset failed on Ubuntu boot

Tags: nvidia

Note that this is not a new install!  I have had this computer for months and recently did some machine learning in a jupyter notebook, so I was using the GPU.  I have previously used pm-hibernate to turn off my machine without too much issue.  However, this time I decided to put it to sleep (while the jupyter-notebook kernel was active)  I try to wake my computer, the screen is completely frozen, and then I do a hard reboot by flicking the power on and off... and get this error message:

```
nvidia-gpu 0000:01:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000040
ucsi_ccg 0-0000: i2c_transfer failed -110
ucsi_ccg 0-0000: failed to reset PPM!
ucsi_ccg 0-0000: PPM init failed (-110)
```

my machine cannot boot.  I have looked online for help but most of it is for new system builds.  I do not know what nvidia driver I am using and I looked for installed ones but I have many installed through apt.  I cannot use nvidia-smi since my graphics card is not communicating.  How can I get my graphics card to respond?  (it is a RTX-2060)

Answer (score 1):

I just typed `sudo ubuntu-drivers install` and my machine booted, and I was able to use my graphics card as normal.  (I have had trouble with nvidia drivers before so I feel pretty lucky that this worked.)

Comment: Where did you type this command ?

Comment: I think if you hit F1 or Ctrl+F1 or Ctrl + Alt + F1 you enter TTY mode.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks .. excuse me. What is there version of nvidia did you install